# 7 days - probability distribution

Tags: probability

The probability that I go to the gym on any given day of the week is 30%.
Find the probability distribution of the number of times that I go to the gym over the course of one week (7 days).

My solution:
 = C(7, ) * 0.3^k * 0.7^(7-k)

for k = 0, 1, 2, ..., 7.

My question is: once I solve for each k (0 through 7), am I adding or multiplying?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the probabilities for each possibility (and they are mutually exclusive) then the probabilities should ***add*** up to $1$.

See the [probability axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms)

Comment: Thank you. By adding them, does that answer the "the probability distribution of the number of times that I go to the gym over the course of one week (7 days). "

Comment: The probability distribution is essentially the probabilities for each of the eight possible number of days. Assuming independence, you have already done this